# After uninstalling Ubuntu, how to remove the "Ubuntu" entry from the Windows boot selection?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, bootloader

After uninstalling dual-boot ubuntu on my laptop, every time during start-up I get stuck on a screen like this:

[image: Screenshot]

There is no entry for Ubuntu in the `Boot` tab of `msconfig`:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I delete the Ubuntu entry and avoid getting stuck on this screen at every boot?

Comment: That issue seems cautionary about letting Windows decide boot environment. Grub2 seems to be easier to edit and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

After an absurd amount of searching and trying stuff, I found [this method](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/148748-how-delete-boot-loader-entry-boot-menu-startup-windows.html) which finally worked for me.

1. Open a command promt `cmd` with admin rights (has to be command prompt, powershell doesn't work).
2. Type `bcdedit` and press `Enter`.
3. In the output, look for the entry where `description` is `Ubuntu`.
4. Copy the `identifier` from your output by selecting with the mouse and pressing `Ctrl+C`. The `identifier` is a string of letters and numbers in brackets, in my case `{34b9d878-c12b-11eb-9b58-b5e6ae92ed4c}`.
5. Type `bcdedit /delete {your-identifier}` where in place of `{your-identifier}` you paste the copied identifier by pressing `Ctrl+V`, then press `Enter`.
6. Type `bcdedit` again and press `Enter`, then check the output to make sure the Ubuntu entry has disappeared.

[image: Screenshot]